# Редиректит, используя адрес из DOCUMENT_ROOT

Tags: редирект, .htaccess, joomla

Здравствуйте! Добавляю в htaccess следующую инструкцию:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Это чтобы все страницы без слеша в конце ссылки редиректил на страницы со слешем. Редирект происходит, вот только редиректит он меня вот так: при попытке запросить страницу без слеша `http://домен.ru/katalog` редирект происходит на `http://домен.ru/home/пользователь_хостинга/data/www/домен.ru/katalog/` а не на `http://домен.ru/katalog/`

С чем это может быть связано? Заранее спасибо! С уважением.

Answer (score 1):

Может это поможет:

```
RewriteBase /
```